# jQuery - select an element which contain n number of duplicate child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is the HTML I have to work with. The `spacer` classes basically indent the text.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   HEADING 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   SUBHEADING 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   SUBHEADING 2
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   HEADING 2
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How should I form my jQuery selectors so that I'm able to grab the rows for Headings? and for Subheadings?

I've tried `$(tr).has('td.spacer')` but this doesn't really help since they all use it and have multiples (2 for "headings" and 3 for "subheadings")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter

```
var f = function(n) {
    return function() {
        return $(this).find('.spacer').length === n;
    }
}

var headings   = $('td').filter( f(2) );
var subheading = $('td').filter( f(3) ); 
// ..etc
```

```js
var f = function(n) {return function() {return $(this).find('.spacer').length === n}};

$('td').filter( f(2) ).css('color','red');
$('td').filter( f(3) ).css('color','blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   HEADING 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   SUBHEADING 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   SUBHEADING 2
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   <span class="spacer"></span>
   HEADING 2
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Get based on the count of `.spacer` span element. Use combination of [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo class selectors.

```js
// get head - which don't have 3rd `spacer` element
$('tr:has(:not(td .spacer:nth-child(3)))').css('color', 'green');

// get subhead - which have 3rd `spacer` element
$('tr:has(td .spacer:nth-child(3))').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      HEADING 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      SUBHEADING 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      SUBHEADING 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      HEADING 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like this CSS approach too! Unfortunately, I'm also trying to make it work for a browser that does not support `nth-child` ):

Comment: @Katie - this is jQuery's `nth-child`, not CSS, this one is cross-browser

Comment: @adeneo Good to know!!